# Getting a secure session object from a non secure page in ASP

Tags: session, ssl, asp-classic, iis-6, iis-7.5

I'm maintaining a system built in ASP.

The login process is in SSL. Meaning, when the user clicks on "Login", his user name and password are sent securely to the server.
The login process produces a Session object, which is the ID of the now logged-in user.

After finishing the login process, the page redirects the browser to a non secure page. This page tries to access the ID Session object.

Until last week, this worked fine. Our system was running on IIS6.0, and the non-secure page could access this Secure ID Session object.
However, after switching over to IIS7.5, this inevitable security hole was closed(or so I assume). The non-secure page cannot access the Secure ID Session object anymore.

Access to the object is done simply like this:

```
string ID = Session(SESSION_USER_ID)
```

just to check things out, I tried access a non-secure Session object from the Secure login pages - this failed as well.

Is there any way to access a Secure Session object from a non-secure page?

BTW, I've probably mistaken with some of the terms here, but I think the scenario is more or less clear. Please tell me if this is not the case.

Comment: Are the SSL and non SSL sites in the same application? Sessions cannot be shared between different application, but should be within the same.

Comment: They are in the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this problem before, I ended up getting around it by, when changing into or out of SSL, calling a function that would write the session variables to cookies, and then read back from the cookies into the SSL session variables.